# Access variable in once from another class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, ios8

I have Two classes in have declared string in one variable and trying access from another class. have initiated getter setter in between them still getting null value when I try to print from subclass.

CustomerCarSelection.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface CustomerCarSelection : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource>

    @property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *carListTableView;
    - (IBAction)next:(id)sender;

    @property NSString *carSelectedForService;

    @end
```

customerCarSelection.m

```
    #import "CustomerCarSelection.h"
    #import <Parse/Parse.h>
    #import "carSelectCellTableViewCell.h"
    #import "ServiceResultView.h"
    @interface CustomerCarSelection ()

    @end

    @implementation CustomerCarSelection


    @synthesize carListTableView;
    @synthesize carSelectedForService;
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        ServiceResultView *service = [[ServiceResultView alloc]init];
        service.pointer = self;
    }
    -(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        NSLog(@"cell tabbed");
        PFObject *temp = [cellDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        carSelectedForService = temp.objectId;

        NSLog(@"%@", carSelectedForService);

    }
```

serviceResultView.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import "CustomerCarSelection.h"
    @interface ServiceResultView : UIViewController
    {
        CustomerCarSelection *pointer;
    }
    @property (nonatomic, retain) CustomerCarSelection *pointer;

    - (IBAction)confirm:(id)sender;

    @end
```

serviceResultView.m

```
    #import "ServiceResultView.h"
    #import "CustomerCarSelection.h"
    @interface ServiceResultView ()

    @end

    @implementation ServiceResultView
    @synthesize pointer;
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.




        NSString *carResult = pointer.carSelectedForService;
        NSLog(@"%@", carResult);

    }
```

Where am I making mistake. When the cell tabbed it will assign object id to the String i trying access that object from another class

Comment: My guess is that you are creating a whole new object (`[[ServiceResultView alloc]init]`) and not using the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CustomerCarSelection.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomerCarSelection : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *carListTableView;

- (IBAction)next:(id)sender;



@end


customerCarSelection.m

#import "CustomerCarSelection.h"
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import "carSelectCellTableViewCell.h"
#import "ServiceResultView.h"
@interface CustomerCarSelection ()

@end

@implementation CustomerCarSelection


@synthesize carListTableView;
@synthesize carSelectedForService;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell tabbed");
    PFObject *temp = [cellDetails objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    serviceResultView *obj = [serviceResultView alloc] init];
    obj.carSelectedForService = temp.objectId;

    NSLog(@"%@", obj.carSelectedForService);

}


serviceResultView.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "CustomerCarSelection.h"
@interface ServiceResultView : UIViewController
@property NSString *carSelectedForService;
- (IBAction)confirm:(id)sender;

@end

serviceResultView.m

#import "ServiceResultView.h"
#import "CustomerCarSelection.h"
@interface ServiceResultView ()

@end

@implementation ServiceResultView
@synthesize pointer;
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.




    NSLog(@"%@", self.carSelectedForService);

}
```

Comment: Still getting null printed.

Comment: did your celldetails contains any data or not. first confim that, celldetail should not be null.

Comment: I got objects in cell brother still printing cell